# Markdown: escape all backslashes in codeblock

Tags: escaping, markdown

In a Markdown code block I have many backslashes and other characters that I want to be displayed as is without being converted to another character, e.g. `\2` will remain `\2` and not be converted to `STX`.

I'm afraid that someone will copy identifiers from the Markdown codeblock itself and attempt to run a query on it, etc. without realizing the identifiers have been escaped (I work with many non-dev folk who happen to use GitHub).

Is it possible to do this in the codeblock without escaping each individual character? I suppose I'm asking for something like Python 3's raw strings: `r"""\2"""` but as a Markdown codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Markdown environment¹ that converts `\2` to `STX` in code blocks. They are usually rendered verbatim, possibly with syntax highlighting added.

Here is an example:

```
\2
```

Your document probably doesn't actually contain `\2`, but rather a [start of text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX) control character. [Control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) are non-printing characters:

> In computing and telecommunication, a **control character** or **non-printing character** (**NPC**) is a code point (a number) in a character set, that does not represent a written symbol. They are used as [in-band signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-band_signaling) to cause effects other than the addition of a symbol to the text. All other characters are mainly **printing**, **printable**, or **graphic characters**, except perhaps for the "space" character (see ASCII printable characters).

Start of text has the value 2 in both decimal and hexadecimal. Since control codes are non-printing they aren't naturally visible, so we have a few representations to show them:

- `^B` in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)
- The symbol `␂`
- The abbreviation STX
- The character itself, which may be *displayed* as `\2` or `\0002` or `U+0002` or similar

This last one is different from the two characters `\` and `2`. It is *one* character, whose *value* is code point 2, the start text character. It is simply being *shown* as `\2` as a way of being made visible.

If you want the characters `\2`, delete the single start of text character and type `\2`. If you actually want the start of text character, I suggest you leave it as-is.

---

¹Some environments do non-standard things, do pre- or post-processing, or have plugins that affect the rendered result. If your environment really *is* converting `\2` to `␂`, please share details. In that case you might be better off using `\\2` in the source.